# Custom script and css versioning best practices and automation with gruntjs

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, gruntjs, versioning

I've decided to start versioning the custom css and js files i use in my WP themes so that when I update a site a page reload is not needed to display the changes to users(long overdue, I know).

Is just adding a version number as a query string at the end of the call and keeping the real file name static a good practice(as in "script.js?v=xyz")? How will this affect browser caching when the version number is not changed? Will it cache normally and only get a new version when i change the version number?

If the above is the way to go, i would like to automate this with Grunt so when I run my "build" command the PHP file where the files get enqueued in WP gets modified to contain a random hash + the date as the version parameter in the wp_enqueue_script command. I presume that when i run my development command with livereload and everything, the scripts having said version will not affect livereload so i do not need to remove the versioning, correct?
How would you do this, what npm module would you use and what would be the commands i need to add to my Gruntfile.js?

As a sidenote, i know that the version number added by wordpress by default to all scripts and css is considered a security risk as it exposes the WP version you're rolling and i've been removing it via functions.php, but, i would like to enable it, yet have it not use the WP version but something random that gets changed with each WP update. Any idea how one would implement this? I'm surprised that i was not able to find a plugin that does this.

Thank you ver much, community!

Comment: Welcome. We understand lines of code, not literature. Please share your code if you want to expect help. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have certainly done this, as a way of indicating to browsers that they should download a newer version of a stylesheet. This isn't particularly elegant, but one thing I've done is declared cache-busting parameter (xyz in your example) as a PHP constant:

```
// inc/constants.php
define('CACHEPARAMETER', '20161027');
```

And my grunt build task modifies this using  [grunt-text-replace](https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace):

```
replace: {
        cacheparam: {
            src: ['inc/constants.php'],
            overwrite: true,                 // overwrite matched source files
            replacements: [{
                from: /'CACHEPARAMETER', '[0-9]{8}'/g,
                to: "'CACHEPARAMETER', '<%= grunt.template.today('yyyymmdd') %>'"
            }]
        }
    }
```

I'm enqueueing this in functions.php, which I do like this:

```
include "inc/constants.php";
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), CACHEPARAMETER);
```

Hope this helps.